# php if statements causing file to write twice

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have a simple form which takes input and performs a maths equation and displays the results.  It also takes these input and result, and writes the values to a saved text file.  The problem im having is that ive introduced some if statements which is causing the math functions to be run twice per form submission and so the data is being saved to the text file twice per one form submission.  Ill post the code and hopefully someone can point out a better way to do things.

```html
<html>

<?php

//variables and result
function bio($height, $weight, $chest, $waist, $hip) {
    $height = floatval($height);
    $weight = floatval($weight);
    $chest = floatval($chest);
$waist = floatval($waist);
$hip = floatval($hip);
$app = ($height+$weight+$chest+$waist+$hip)   ;


$datawrite1 = fopen("data_file_1.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = 
$height.";".   
$weight.";".  
$chest.";".    
$waist.";". 
$hip.";".    
$app."\n";
        fwrite($datawrite1,$txt);
        fclose($datawrite1);

return $app; 

}

?>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<form action="#result" method="POST" name="form1";">
 <br/>
<label id="label1">height</label>
 <br/>
    <input id="height" name="height" type="number" 
step=".1" max="300"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'"
placeholder="height in cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['height']) ? $_POST['height'] : '';
?>" />
    <br/>
<label id="label1">weight</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="weight" name="weight" type="number" step=".1"  onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'"
placeholder="weight in kgs" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['weight']) ? $_POST['weight'] : '';
 ?>" />
<br/>
<label id="label1">bust / chest</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="chest" name="chest" type="number" step=".1"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'" placeholder="chest in cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['chest']) ? $_POST['chest'] : ''; ?>" />
<br/>
<label id="label1">waist</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="waist" name="waist" type="number" step=".1"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'" placeholder="waist in cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['waist']) ? $_POST['waist'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
<label id="label1">hip</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="hip" name="hip" type="number" step=".1"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'" placeholder="hip in  cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['hip']) ? $_POST['hip'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/> 
   <br/> 
    <br/>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="showDiv()"  id="Login" 
    />

<p id="result">
<?php //handles if empty or 0 input
if 
(!empty($_POST['height']) && !empty($_POST['weight']) && !
 empty($_POST['chest']) && !empty($_POST['waist']) && !empty($_POST['hip'])): 
?>
 <?php 
 if (bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip']) < "16.") 
{
  echo "BMI below 16 (" .bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  .   "), won't proceed"; sleep(3.14);
} 
else 

if (bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  < "2") 
{
  echo "input error detected, please check" ; sleep(3.14);
} 
else 
{
  echo "your score is " . bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  . " % "  ; sleep(3.14);
}
endif;
?>
</p>  

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(bio(…)) { echo "BMI below 16 (" .bio(…) }` - are you really surprised now, that a function that gets _called_ twice, does its _job_ twice? Store the result of the call into a variable, and then use that in both places.

Comment: it is the "else" and extra if statement which causes it.  If i take out one of the "else" instances my problem disappears.

Comment: Even when it goes into the `BMI below 16` branch then? Check again.

Comment: Can you give the code of how id use the variable method you mentioned.  I'd probably learn faster that way.

Comment: `$foo = bio(…); if($foo < 16) { echo "BMI below 16 (".$foo."…"; }`

Comment: thanks, ill give it a run through and see if i can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`< 16.` and `<2` are both matching the if criteria. Try adding a second criteria.

```
if (bio() > 2 and bio() < 16) {
 // do first something
} else if (bio() < 2) {
 // do second something
} else {
 // runs if no criteria is met.
}
```

```html
<html>

<?php

//variables and result
function bio($height, $weight, $chest, $waist, $hip) {
    $height = floatval($height);
    $weight = floatval($weight);
    $chest = floatval($chest);
$waist = floatval($waist);
$hip = floatval($hip);
$app = ($height+$weight+$chest+$waist+$hip)   ;


$datawrite1 = fopen("data_file_1.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = 
$height.";".   
$weight.";".  
$chest.";".    
$waist.";". 
$hip.";".    
$app."\n";
        fwrite($datawrite1,$txt);
        fclose($datawrite1);

return $app; 

}

?>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<form action="#result" method="POST" name="form1";">
 <br/>
<label id="label1">height</label>
 <br/>
    <input id="height" name="height" type="number" 
step=".1" max="300"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'"
placeholder="height in cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['height']) ? $_POST['height'] : '';
?>" />
    <br/>
<label id="label1">weight</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="weight" name="weight" type="number" step=".1"  onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'"
placeholder="weight in kgs" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['weight']) ? $_POST['weight'] : '';
 ?>" />
<br/>
<label id="label1">bust / chest</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="chest" name="chest" type="number" step=".1"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'" placeholder="chest in cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['chest']) ? $_POST['chest'] : ''; ?>" />
<br/>
<label id="label1">waist</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="waist" name="waist" type="number" step=".1"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'" placeholder="waist in cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['waist']) ? $_POST['waist'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
<label id="label1">hip</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="hip" name="hip" type="number" step=".1"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'" placeholder="hip in  cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['hip']) ? $_POST['hip'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/> 
   <br/> 
    <br/>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="showDiv()"  id="Login" 
    />

<p id="result">
<?php //handles if empty or 0 input
if 
(!empty($_POST['height']) && !empty($_POST['weight']) && !empty($_POST['chest']) && !empty($_POST['waist']) && !empty($_POST['hip'])):
?>
 <?php 
 if (bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip']) < "16.") && (bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  > "2")
{
  echo "BMI below 16 (" .bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  .   "), won't proceed"; sleep(3.14);
} 
else 

if (bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  < "2")
{
  echo "input error detected, please check" ; sleep(3.14);
} 
else 
{
  echo "your score is " . bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  . " % "  ; sleep(3.14);
}
endif;
?>
</p>  

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Those criteria are just examples.  If i change them to something else the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using a dummy function to run the if statements, but i dont think it is very elegant solution or good practise:

```html
<html>

<?php

//variables and result
function bio($height, $weight, $chest, $waist, $hip) {
    $height = floatval($height);
    $weight = floatval($weight);
    $chest = floatval($chest);
$waist = floatval($waist);
$hip = floatval($hip);
$app = ($height+$weight+$chest+$waist+$hip)   ;

$datawrite1 = fopen("data_file_1.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = 
$height.";".   
$weight.";".  
$chest.";".    
$waist.";". 
$hip.";".    
$app."\n";
        fwrite($datawrite1,$txt);
        fclose($datawrite1);

return $app; 


}

?>

<?php

//variables and result
function bio2($height, $weight, $chest, $waist, $hip) {
    $height = floatval($height);
    $weight = floatval($weight);
    $chest = floatval($chest);
$waist = floatval($waist);
$hip = floatval($hip);
$app2 = ($height+$weight+$chest+$waist+$hip)   ;




return $app2; 

}

?>


<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<form action="#result" method="POST" name="form1";">
 <br/>
<label id="label1">height</label>
 <br/>
    <input id="height" name="height" type="number" 
step=".1" max="300"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'"
placeholder="height in cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['height']) ? $_POST['height'] : '';
?>" />
    <br/>
<label id="label1">weight</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="weight" name="weight" type="number" step=".1"  onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'"
placeholder="weight in kgs" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['weight']) ? $_POST['weight'] : '';
 ?>" />
<br/>
<label id="label1">bust / chest</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="chest" name="chest" type="number" step=".1"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'" placeholder="chest in cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['chest']) ? $_POST['chest'] : ''; ?>" />
<br/>
<label id="label1">waist</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="waist" name="waist" type="number" step=".1"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'" placeholder="waist in cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['waist']) ? $_POST['waist'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
<label id="label1">hip</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="hip" name="hip" type="number" step=".1"
 onblur="this.style.backgroundColor=/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit': '#fec7ce'" placeholder="hip in  cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['hip']) ? $_POST['hip'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/> 
   <br/> 
    <br/>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="showDiv()"  id="Login" 
    />

<p id="result">
<?php //handles if empty or 0 input
if 
(!empty($_POST['height']) && !empty($_POST['weight']) && !
 empty($_POST['chest']) && !empty($_POST['waist']) && !empty($_POST['hip'])): 
?>
 <?php 
 if (bio2($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip']) < "16.") 
{
  echo "BMI below 16 (" .bio2($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  .   "), won't proceed"; sleep(3.14);
} 
else 

if (bio2($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  > "50") 
{
  echo "input error detected, please check" ; sleep(3.14);
} 
else 
{
  echo "your score is " . bio($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hip'])  . " % "  ; sleep(3.14);



}
endif;
?>
</p>  

</form>

</body>
</html>
```